# I want to put all the database data in the list

Tags: c#, mysql, database, list

```
 List<int> values = new List<int>();

string sql = "SELECT Values_To_Add FROM table";

command.CommandText = sql;

MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(); 
while(reader.Read())
{
    values.Add(reader["Values_To_Add "]);
}
```

> Error  CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'int'

Someone's idea?

Comment: Cast to `int`? `int.TryParse()` the field value? Use a `DataTable`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should cast the value from the reader as integer.
You can do it safely like this:

```
 var intValue = reader["Values_To_Add"] as int?;
 if (intValue != null) { values.Add(intValue.Value); }
```